# jpeg_write_view error in boost::gil

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

I am now learning how to use generic image library in boost, and the following codes illustrate how to write some raw data to a jpeg file:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *src_pixels;
    int src_row_bytes = 200;
    src_pixels = new unsigned char [200*500];
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<200; j++)
            src_pixels[i*200+j]= j;
    }
    char *dst_pixels;
    dst_pixels = new char [200*500];
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<200; j++)
            dst_pixels[i*200+j]= j;
    }
    gray8c_view_t my_view = interleaved_view(200,500,(const gray8_pixel_t*)src_pixels,src_row_bytes);
    gray8s_view_t your_view = interleaved_view(200,500,( gray8s_pixel_t*)dst_pixels,src_row_bytes); 

    jpeg_write_view("C:/file_1_copy.jpg", my_view);
    jpeg_write_view("C:/file_2_copy.jpg", your_view);

     delete []src_pixels;
     delete []dst_pixels;

    return 0;
}
```

However, it seems   `jpeg_write_view("C:/file_2_copy.jpg", your_view);` cannot be compiled, and the following error messages are given:

```
Error   2   error C2338: jpeg_write_support<View>::is_supported
```

I do not how I could make it compile. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

`

Comment: Looking at the header files ([here](http://www.boost.org/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp) and [here](http://www.boost.org/boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io_private.hpp)) I think `jpeg_write_support<View>::is_supported` is only true for views that have a channel type that is unsigned and of 8 bits. I don't know whether there is a good reason for that or whether its simply an oversight. Maybe someone with more knowledge will be able to help you.

Comment: @cv_and_he - great then please add the solution - what to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Boost v1.75** the function `boost::gil::jpeg_read_image(...)` is still available in this header `#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg/old.hpp>`.

The new equivalent API (I think from Boost.GIL v1.68) is

```
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg.hpp>
boost::gil::write_view();
```

to manage JPEG use `boost::gil::jpeg_tag()`.

Example:

```
boost::gil::write_view("out.jpg", img_view, boost::gil::jpeg_tag());
```